# MULTIPLE RTX 2080 GPU's in Blender 2.9 not being utilized

Tags: gpu

First up, I am a complete noob when it comes to Blender, so I apologize in advance if I am asking rookie questions.

I am a specialist box builder for the pro level film & video editing industry. I have just completed a build for a client at FOX STUDIO'S in Sydney who uses Blender heavily.

The specs on the machine are as follows:

Thread Ripper 3970X
128 gig ram
2 x Nvidia  2080 Super
Samsung NVME 970 EVO+ 1TB systems drive
2 x Force MP600 series Gen4 NVMe PCIe M.2 SSD 2TB in raid 0
Corsair 1600W AXi digital PSU
Win 10 pro
TRX40-E ROG STRIX RTX40-E-GAMING MB
water cooling, etc.

I installed Blender V 2.9.0 It is seeing and recognizing the 2 x Nvidia GPU's and allows me to select them for the rendering choices, however regardless of the settings that I choose, Windows is only showing 1 x RTX GPU being used. I can get it to use both the CPU and 1 x GPU at the same time, but no matter what I do, I cannot get it to use both GPU's at the same time.

Is this a Blender bug, or am I missing something critical? a setting or driver?

Any help would be appreciated.

Kind Regards

Colin. R. Selby
Eye Candy Labs.
Sydney, Australia

Comment: I think this might be of use to you.
https://blenderartists.org/t/eevee-multigpu-yes-you-can/1195530

Comment: Have you bridged the GPUs to with an SLI cord to act as one?

Comment: They should not be linked in SLI!

Comment: Are you rendering a scene that is complex enough to use the GPU significantly? Try using one of the scenes from the blenchmark. Set blender to use gpy only, you should see only two tiles being rendered simultaneously.